# British usage: add verb forms of "do" after a conditional

Tags: british-english, word-usage

Is it standard British usage to add forms of the verb "Do" after a conditional like "Would"? e.g., If I could, I would do"?

Comment: Interesting question. It's completely weird by American standards; it marks text as British just as fast as RP would in speech.

Comment: I'd say it's about 50 - 50, but your example is unbalanced.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth by which you mean that _do_ is added after _could_ as well as _would_?

Comment: I don't see how "after a conditional" makes any difference here. It's no different with, say, *"Everybody dies sooner or later. You will [**do**] too."*. I can't see anything weird about including ***do*** there (or not - they're both fine to my BrE ear).

Comment: No, adding 'do' after a 'conditional' (or, as FF says, modal in general). Adding a 'do' after your 'could' would not cause any consternation over here.

Comment: It is less a matter of adding and more a matter of not removing, no?  'You know I would.' contracts 'You know that I would do so'.  The question is just how economical to be.  The proof is 'He has to!'.  That is obviously a place where 'do so' is removed, and if there were a 'do' it would be left and not added.

Answer (score 2):

What is going on here is not the addition of 'do', and has little to do with conditionals in particular.   It presents a different prioritization of reduction rules.

There is no added 'do'.  The construction in your example is that 'would', for instance, takes another verb, and that in backward references the phrase would therefore properly end with 'would do so'.  Nor does the auxiliary verb have to be 'do'.

AmE more aggressively suppresses auxiliary verbs for which the objects have already been suppressed.

> He has done that, and I would do so, too.
>
> He pays his rent because he has to do so.
>
> He will be dead before you are so.
>
> You fill out tax forms faster than I do so.

becomes these in AmE.

> He has done that and I would, too.
>
> He does that because he has to.
>
> He will be dead before you.
>
> You fill out tax forms faster than I.

In BrE, you are more likely to remove the object of the verb, without removing the verb itself.

The 'exception that proves the rule' is the optional hanging verb in the last two examples.  When the omitted part is less surely guaranteed to be a simple back-reference like 'so' or 'that', it is sometimes slightly clearer to hint at the omission.  So sometimes these examples have their terminal auxiliary verbs.  But it sounds more well-considered when they are omitted as well.

Comment: *"You work faster than I do so"?* No! Not in AmE, at least.

Comment: It is proper, make work something much more complicated with the same gist like 'perform our assigned function', and you can hear it right.  You are just used to hearing it already reduced.  When words are short, reductions become almost mandatory.  And I agree that is one that would not be heard in that form in public.

Comment: I don't think that's it. You use *"do so"* when there's an object in the first verb, but you need to leave out the *"so"* when there's no object. *"You fill out **these forms** faster than I do so*" because there's an object: *"these forms"*. Same for your first and third examples. But your fourth example sounds wrong to me.

Comment: Right, the reduction is forced.  But it is a reduction.  Use a word less familiar than 'work' without an object like, like 'pirouette', and the awkwardness reduces.  The problem is "Why would you say 'do so' instead of just repeating 'work'?"

Comment: *"You pirouette better than I do so"*? That's just as bad. The *"so"* works like a pronoun standing for the object or the complement, and if there's no object or complement, it can't stand for anything, so it's ungrammatical.

Comment: "If you want to work, then do so"  No object on work, and that is perfectly grammatical.  Thus 'so' cannot refer to the object of work.

Comment: Okay. Maybe you're right. Your examples still sound wrong to me.

Comment: I will stuff the phrase, to make it sound more natural.  It was a bad choice on my part.  But if the 'so' was a 'that', in 'You "pirouette" better than I do so'  you would say that 'that' is 'pirouette' (and perhaps your speaker did not agree it was the right choice of word) not some reference to a missing object.

Answer (score 0):

In colloquial speech, yes. In formal written or spoken English, no.

Reason: in the example you present, the 'do' is valid, but redundant.

Comment: Hello The. What we're really looking for (on this or any other Stack Exchange site) is a supported answer: one that you can support with authoritative references (in this case a dictionary, grammar, or article say). [Matt Gutting]

Comment: Ugh... okay. Noted. Bit strange though... given the nature of the language LOL!

Comment: This answer reads like there is some weird rule in formal English that any word that can be removed, must be removed. But that is not true of any variety, register, or dialect of English, or any other language for that matter.